# Is it possible to make one public ip point at different servers within a local network?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, subdomain

Title is a bit vague so here i go!

Basically i have setup a local dns server that allows me to use my local network using hostnames.

e.g. dns.subdomain.home

i would like all these servers to be accessible from the internet using one of my domains. So for example -

If i want to use web.subdomain.home i want it to map to web.subdomain.example.com and i only want to be able use functions given by web.subdomain.home

I only have one public IP inbound to my local network and is dynamic so i am using dyndns to update the ip address constantly when modem resets (which is almost never)

My domain is also hosted on a shared hosting service.

Wondering if this is possible or not?

Thanks

Comment: It depends what you want to do with those servers. Are those http servers? or do they have other functions? What you ask is possible, but the tools needed vary greatly depending on what is running there.
Also, your example is hard to understand. Please use .com for public address and .local for local ones. (just so we can understand)

Comment: @Bruno9779 sorry i should have mentioned a bit about what i want to do. Not all will have http servers on but i may in the future want to have more than one http server. Each server needs to be independant from the other

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

One option (well, potentially) is called a [one-to-many NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#One-to-many_NATs), and is even the most common kind of NAT.